# ValueError: how to extract `<a href >` from a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I want to get `<a href>` from this dataframe, but instead I get:

`ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index.`

This is what the DataFrame looks like

```py
df.head(7)
0   <ul class="toc"> <li class="first"><a href="#d...
1   <ul class="toc"> <li><a href="#d17e906">1. LEE...
2   <ul class="toc"> <li><a href="#d17e974">2.1 Be...
3   <ul class="toc"> <li><a href="#d17e6333">3.1. ...
4   <ul class="toc"> <li><a href="#d17e23490">4.1 ...
5   <ul class="toc"> <li><a href="#d17e27196">5.1 ...
6   <ul class="toc"> <li><a href="#d17e54643">Bijl...
7   <ul class="toc"> <li><a href="#d17e55852">31. ...
```

This is the code I am using.

```py
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
ul_toc = soup.find_all('ul', class_= 'toc')
links = []
for a_tag in ul_toc:
    extract= a_tag.find_all('li')
    for each in extract:
        try:
            link = each.find('a')['href']
            links.append(link)
        except:
            pass
df['Link'] = links
```

I am not sure what I am missing with the above code.

Comment: Are you trying to extract the 'a hef' value of the text. I mean only the 3.1, 4.1, ..
What python version are you using? What pandas version are you using?

Comment: I try to extract href value. I mean #d17e.. with Python 3.8.0 and pandas 0.24.2

Answer (score 0):

I can find it myself.

```
toc_class= soup.find_all('ul', class_='toc')
df= pd.DataFrame(data= toc_class)

links = []
for a_tag in toc_class:
    extract= a_tag.find('li')
    for each in extract:
        try:
            link = each.get('href')
            links.append(link)
        except:
            pass

df['Link'] = links
df
```

and this is the output:

```
0                                                        Link
0   <ul class="toc"> <li class="first"><a href="#d...   #d17e58
1   <ul class="toc"> <li><a href="#d17e906">1. LEE...   #d17e906
2   <ul class="toc"> <li><a href="#d17e974">2.1 Be...   #d17e974
3   <ul class="toc"> <li><a href="#d17e6333">3.1. ...   #d17e6333
4   <ul class="toc"> <li><a href="#d17e23490">4.1 ...   #d17e23490
5   <ul class="toc"> <li><a href="#d17e27196">5.1 ...   #d17e27196
6   <ul class="toc"> <li><a href="#d17e54643">Bijl...   #d17e54643
7   <ul class="toc"> <li><a href="#d17e55852">31. ...   #d17e55852
```